# asp.net, using the data pulled during login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a login page that leads to a homepage, the login page pulls from a view in the database to verify username and password (the view has 3 columns, username, password, and name) it selects all the data including the name but only uses the username and password.

This is the login code:

```
  protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblerror.Visible = false;     
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurveySystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE Username=@username AND Password= @password";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserNameTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordTextBox.Text);

        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Session["Username"] = UserNameTextBox;
            Session["Password"] = PasswordTextBox;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
           }
          else
            {
                lblerror.Visible = true;
                lblerror.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password Combination";
            }
            conn.Close();
 }
```

What i want to do is display a welcome message on the homepage, "Welcome (The name of the user whose id was just used)". How can this be done so that the homepage will always have the person's name until he/she logs out, meaning even if they go into other pages back and forth while logged in. I'm using Sql server for my database.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.  Do not store passwords in session state.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use ASP.Net's built-in membership system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

On your code on login just get the User Name column and pass it to a session

```
Session["Name"] = reader["Name"].ToString() //Supposed your column name is called Name
```

Check this link on how to get retrieve column value on datareader: [Retrieving Data Using a C# .NET DataReader](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html)

Then on Your  Master page header add label control with id lblusername

```
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">
Welcome :
<asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then on your code behind just Add

```
lblUserNAme.Text =  Session["Name"].toString();
```

on your master page page_load

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're storing the user's name in Session["Username"] so you can retrieve that value after a successful login and set your label's text to it.

You can do this in a code behind, or in-line in the *.aspx:

```
Welcome <%= Session["Username"] %>!
```

Comment: the "username" is the "userID" that the person logged in with, the name is the person's name (which is what i need after the login) which is included in the select statement. Would it be possible to store that in a new session? like Session["Name"] and assign that to some variable and pull from it?